# Jerky flash playback in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash, boot-camp

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium on an iMac 24" (early 2008) using BootCamp.

Sometimes when I try and play a video in full screen I get jerky playback, although never when watching YouTube videos oddly enough.

I'm currently using Chrome as my browser of choice.

As a fairly new convert (back) to Windows is this is a known issue with Windows 7, flash, the browser or something to do with BootCamp?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser(s)? Or updating your flash plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I read (somewhere) that just clearing the browsing history should fix it. It did and Flash now seems to be behaving itself in Chrome.